# Transferring files between two Apple ID accounts

Tags: iphone, itunes, icloud, apple-id

I am currently in a joint Apple ID account and I'd like to transfer the files and data in my iPhone to a new individual account I created. My iCloud storage is completely full up on the joint account.

Q: **Is there a way to transfer my data onto my Mac or a new iCloud server so I can put them onto my new Apple ID account?**

Comment: Can you please specify "the files and data in my iPhone"? Some files cannot be transferred while others can.

Comment: Not a complete anwer, but for Contacts you can export them on iCloud.com and import them on your Mac. When your Mac is signed in to the new Apple ID, all imported contacts will by synced with the new Apple ID

Answer (score 1):

I guess each Apple ID has a dedicated iCloud account.  Login and logout with each individual Apple ID from your MAC and use terminal to access all the documents belong to each Apple ID that are stored in the iCloud . After you access the iCloud account you can move files from the iCloud account to your personal Desktop or anywhere you want.

Try the following Terminal commands:

```
cd ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs
mv fileName.ext folderName
```

Comment: While your answer may provide the correct solution, we prefer for answers to be self-contained. Please include the relevant pieces of information and/or the actual commands in your response. This protects your answer against link rot, and keeps the OP from having to open multiple webpages.